# How to exclude certain urls from django debug tool bar?

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

My settings.py file looks like-

```
import os

# This file contains Django settings for lower environments that use the Django Debug Toolbar.
# Currently those envronments are DEV and QA.
from core.settings import *  # noqa: F403

# We need the ability to disable debug_toolbar for regression tests.
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG_MODE', 'FALSE').upper() == 'TRUE'

def toolbar_callback(request):
    return DEBUG


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK": toolbar_callback,
}

INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar', ]  # noqa: F405
MIDDLEWARE += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', ]  # noqa: F405
```

I want to exclude certain pages from loading debug toolbar. The reason being that the pages have a lot of SQL and debug toolbar is taking too long to load and hence page results in a timeout

Answer (score 2):

The value of `SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK` determines if debug toolbar
ought to be used on the page. Therefore you can exclude
specific URLs/URL-patterns by evaluating the request path. For example with
generator expression:

```
if DEBUG:
    patterns = [
        "/foo/bar/",
        "/baz/",
    ]
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': lambda request: not any(p in request.path for p in patterns),
    }
```